# Switching hosting from Google Apps to GoDaddy

Tags: google, dns, godaddy

I am in a pickle here. I just bought a hosting service from GoDaddy and I already have a domain registered with Google Apps.

So I went into the domain control center from Google Apps and I changed the nameservers to point to GoDaddy's and then I deleted all the A records and also removed the www and main CNAME. Then I created an A record with host "@" which points to the IP address I got from GoDaddy (this is the server address I see under the category Server in the GoDaddy Hosting Control Center). Also, I see that in this domain center, the domain forwarding is set to forward to my address "www.domainsite.com".

So right now when I go to my website I see the error "This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later."

Does anyone know how to set this up properly or know what problem I could be having?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this? I am facing same problem. What happens when you change only the A record to the hosting IP? Won't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you change the nameservers you don't have to delete any other records because they are not being used.

Verify that the nameservers have been changed by doing a whois look up on the domain (I use http://who.is). If it has changed then the problem is on Go Daddy's side.

Their support should be able to help you fix the DNS records.

Answer (score 1):

Sahir,

It would be really helpful if you can figure out that either your domain on google apps is pointing properly to your godaddy hosting or not.

You can do the test by running the following command in your command prompt

tracert www.yourdomain.com

If possible kindly paste the results so that i can suggest you further.

Thanks